# How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}cos(\frac{\pi n}{n+1})= -\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

I tried to prove by using definition for divergence:

> We say that a sequence $a_n$ diverges to $-\infty$ if for every $M>0$, there is an integer $n_0$ such that $a_n < -M$ whenever $n>n_0$

So I start:
$$\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}cos(\frac{\pi n}{n+1}) < -M$$
Because $|cos x|\leq 1:$
$$-\frac{n}{2} \leq -\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}cos(\frac{\pi n}{n+1}) < -M$$
$$-\frac{n}{2} < -M$$
$$n>2M$$

Therefore $n_0$ exists and we can say (for example): $n_0=2M+1$.

Is this correct? Is there some other way we could prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Sorry, your first inequality is not correct.

The only way is to write

$$\cos(\frac{\pi n}{n+1})=\cos(\pi-\frac{\pi}{n+1})$$
$$=-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$$

And

$$\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{n}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

But, for $ n $ great enough $(n\ge N_1)$, we have
$$-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1})<-\frac 12$$
since it goes to $ -1$.
thus

$$n>N_1\;\implies \; a_n<-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4}$$
Given $ M>0 $

You just need to find $ N_2 $ such that
$$n> N_2 \;\implies \; \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4}>M$$

You can take $ N_2=16M^2$.

Finally, if you take $ N=\max(N_1,N_2) $, then

$$n>N\;\;\implies \;\;a_n<-M$$

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have like no idea about this being proof enough for you but we usually do this:
$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+1}\right)= -\infty
$

$
1. \frac{\pi n}{n+1} = \frac{\pi }{1+\frac{1}{n} } 
$ // divide by n

for $n\to
 \infty ,  \frac{1}{n} = 0 
$

$
\frac{\pi }{1+\frac{1}{n} } = \frac{\pi }{1+0}
$
so $\cos(\pi) = -1$  // so to get to $-\infty$  we only need to show  now that:

$ 
2. \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}} \to \infty  
$ // divide by n again

$ 
\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{n}{n\cdot\left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right) } 
$

for
$n->  \infty, \frac{1}{n} = 0 
$
and
$  \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0 
$

so we have
$
 \frac{1}{1\cdot( 0 + 0) }  = \frac{1}{0}
$ that goes to infinity

so we end with
$
 \infty \cdot -1  = -\infty$

Take care! I did not write the lim in every row because of fatal lazyness

Comment: Also you are using the fact that $\lim f \, g = \lim f\,\lim g$ which is true when $ \lim f\,\lim g$ both exist (I'm not saying "only when").

Comment: Though you did not even try to make any proposals for improvement, your comment is not even a comment since it laks content. Where is my post worse then others?

Comment: Instead of writing $=$, use \to which gives $\to$, as $\frac 1 0$ is undefined. I didn't edit that as I don't know whether you're doing it unintentionally or not,

Comment: Thank you PNDas this was really helpful now! I am sorry for beeing rude.